# Death of two of Aharon's sons

Tags: death, yom-kippur, grapes-wine

On Yom Kippur we read Parshas Acharei Mos, which discusses the death of two of Aharon's sons. [Medrash Vayikra Rabba 20:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37459&st=&pgnum=58) says that they died as they were drunk on wine (Shetuyei Yayin). How were they able to get drunk on wine in the Midbar, where they only had the Man to eat (to the best of my knowledge Man was only food, not drinks) and there were no vines growing in the area?

Comment: ...and had to have water supplied miraculously via rocks, you mean?

Comment: does it say they were drunk on wine? Maybe they had some brewskies or perhaps a glass of mead. If they shlepped rice with them from the Nile delta they could have made sake. 

Alternatively, just like they took cattle with them from Egypt the could have taken any alcoholic beverage as well.

Comment: My point was that we shouldn't need a specific source if we can easily conjure a myriad number of ways that it could have occurred. the same way, m'stama, they lit shabbos candles, but there is no source that they had wax or olive oil etc.

Comment: There had to be wine somehow if the Jews were going to elevate the nesachim as prescribed in the Torah.

Comment: And the question is there a source as to how there was wine?

Comment: I believe we hold that milk makes you drunk l'inyan mikdash.

Comment: @GershonGold Do you have any reasons to assume the man couldn't be wine?

Comment: @GershonGold I think both your above comments should be added to the question. FTR I think Shtuyei Yayin can be an idiom, and I think the if it _wasn't_ able to be wine it should have been mentioned somewhere. Besides, congealed wine is a solid and still problematic.

Comment: @IsaacMoses It's a machloket tanaaim if nesachim were offered in the midbar. Pshat of Bamidbar 15:2 seems to say not so, but see Sifri there for opinions.

Answer (score 2):

[Mechilta Parshas Yisro 18:9](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=14131&st=%u05D8%u05E2%u05DD%20%u05D9%u05D9%u05DF) says that in the well of Miriam you were able to taste honey, milk, new wine, old wine.

ר׳ אלעזר המודעי אומר בטובת הבאר הגיד לו אמר לו באר שנתן לנו המקום אנו
טועמין בה טעם דבש טעם חלב טעם יין חדש טעם יין ישן

Perhaps this was the way Nadav and Avihu were Shetuyai Yayin.

Comment: Any evidence that the prohibition extends to things that miraculously taste like wine? Or is there some source that interprets that the water actually became wine? If the latter, that may explain where [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_at_Cana) came from -the author got the idea from the Mechilta. Kind of like how [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursing_the_fig_tree) is a corruption of the story of [the son of R' Yose from Yokeres](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%90), which occurred when the Church was still editing in new stories.

Comment: @Fred Do we really need to find precedent for a story of turning water to wine? That seems straightforward enough to be thought of independently.

Comment: @DoubleAA - I'm not asking for a precedent, per se, just for clarification of the source or some other source on the same topic. As far as I can tell, the taste of wine does not mean wine itself.

Comment: @Fred I agree taste =! substance. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13932/759 for those two opinions regarding the Manna. Perhaps a similar machloket applies here.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Nice comment and thank you for the link.